# How does this code (parameters (of Primitive Type)) work?

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing

I am new to java and just learned a little bit about methods and classes, and I am really confused about this whole chapter. This code comes from our review powerpoint and I really don't know how to do it. And I feel like the last section should be in the class? But this is how the powerpoint says. Can someone please explain how does this code work and how to get the printout result specifically step by step?? I really appreciate it, thanks!

```
public class MyClass {
    public void swap(int x, int y){
        int temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
}

int w = 10,
z = 20;
MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.swap(w,z);
System.out.println(w + " " + z);
```

Comment: Posting pictures of code is not the same thing as posting the actual code.  You need to [edit] your question and paste the actual *text* of the code into it.

Comment: Yes, the last part should be inside a (main) method. You can put the method inside `MyClass`. The code looks a bit dubious though, because that swap method won't swap anything.

Comment: I would recommend you to go through basic tutorials https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute Java you need a main method somewhere.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

So you can rewrite the example like so to get it executing:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int w = 10,
    z = 20;
    MyClass m = new MyClass();
    m.swap(w,z);
    System.out.println(w + " " + z);
  }
}

public class MyClass {
    public void swap(int x, int y) {
        int temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
}
```

The whole point of this code example is that Java passes primitive types by value and not by reference. Look at the main method. You have two integers, w=10 and z=20. After that you pass w and z to the swap method. Since java passes these primitive types as values, the original w and z are not modified by the swap, which is proven by the println where w is still 10 and z is still 20.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :-)